# OpsCenter Community, keep data on different cluster

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Trying to setup OpsCenter free keep data on different cluster, but getting error:

```
WARN: Unable to find a matching cluster for node with IP [u'x.x.x.1']; the message was {u'os-load': 0.35}. This usually indicates that an OpsCenter agent is still running on an old node that was decommissioned or is part of a cluster that OpsCenter is no longer monitoring.
```

Same error for second node in cluster :(

But, if I set [dse].enterprise_override = true in cluster config -- everything works fine.

My config is:

```
user@casnode1:~/opscenter/conf/clusters# cat ClusterTest.conf
[jmx]
username =
password =
port = 7199

[kerberos_client_principals]

[kerberos]

[agents]

[kerberos_hostnames]

[kerberos_services]

[storage_cassandra]
seed_hosts = x.x.x.2
api_port = 9160
connect_timeout = 6.0
bind_interface =
connection_pool_size = 5
username =
password =
send_thrift_rpc = True
keyspace = OpsCenter2

[cassandra]
username =
seed_hosts = x.x.x.1, x.x.x.4
api_port = 9160
password =
```

So, the question is: **Is it possible in OpsCenter Community setup different cluster to keep opscenter data?**

OpsCenter version is 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible in OpsCenter Community setup different cluster to keep opscenter data?

It is not.  Storing data on a separate cluster is only supported on DataStax Enterprise clusters.

Note: Using the override you mentioned without permission from DataStax is a violation of the OpsCenter license agreement, and will not be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will think about enterprise.